# Why is Django API Get working but Post not working?

Tags: django, api

> I'm using Django to develop an API, the GET method works but the post
> method gives "Failed to Add." error.
>
> Following is the model,

```
class Video(models.Model):
    VideoId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    VideoName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    FPS = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    TotalFrame = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Duration = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

> The API,

```
@csrf_exempt
def videoApi(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        video = Video.objects.all()
        video_serializer = VideoSerializer(video, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(video_serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        video_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        video_serializer = VideoSerializer(data=video_data)
        if video_serializer.is_valid():
            video_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully!!", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add.", safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        video_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        video = Video.objects.get(VideoId=video_data['VideoId'])
        video_serializer = VideoSerializer(video, data=video_data)
        if video_serializer.is_valid():
            video_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Updated Successfully!!", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Update.", safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        video = Video.objects.get(VideoId=id)
        video.delete()
        return JsonResponse("Deleted Succeffully!!", safe=False)
```

> URLs

```
url(r'^video/$',views.videoApi),
    url(r'^video/([0-9]+)$',views.videoApi),
```

> serializers ,

```
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = '__all__'
```

> JSON Input

```
[{"VideoId": 2, "VideoName": "lol", "FPS": "1", "TotalFrame": "1", "Duration": "1"}]
```

> output ,

```
"Failed to Add."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you haven't explicitly mentioned but from your code snippet it's obvious you are using `django-rest-framework`, so this should fix it:

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, parser_classes
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

@api_view(["POST", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT"])
@parser_classes([JSONParser,])
def videoApi(request)

   # ...snip...

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        video_serializer = VideoSerializer(data=request.data) # .data is important!!
        if video_serializer.is_valid():
            video_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully!!", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add.", safe=False)
```

Better yet, Django-Rest-Framework comes with batteries so for your use-case you can simply write a `ModelViewSet`. For example,

```py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
    
class VideoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing videos.
    """
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
```

and then in your `urls.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import VideoViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r"video", VideoViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

With this, you can perform operations such as:

- `GET /video` - for list
- `GET /video/1` -> for retrieve with ID
- `POST /video` -> for creation
- `PUT /video/1` -> for update with ID
- `DELETE /video/1` -> for deletion with ID

For more information: [`ModelViewSet` docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

Comment: Thank you very much for this! but I tried the first method, I'm still getting the below error.{
    "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}

Comment: @IntizarRafaideen Updated my answer with the fix. A `methods` list was missing from `api_view`. If this answer helped you, please consider marking it as "accepted". :)